# Memory assignment dilema in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management

Consider one C++ function as :

```
A* dum()
{
  A* a = new A()
  doSomethingOnA()
  return a;
}
```

now `dum()` is called as

```
A* b;
b = dum();
```

My question is do we need to assign memory to `b` too?

EDIT: What if I do it as:

```
bool dum(A* a)
{
  // A* a = new A() -- Is this needed?
  doSomethingOnA()
  return 1;
}
```

and dum is called as

```
A* b = new A()
dum(b);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "assign memory"?

Comment: No, `b` is `a` from `dum()`, Because `a` is pointing to the data, and `b` will point to the same address then `a`

Comment: @Borgleader - I mean perfoming b= new A()

Comment: You do not want to allocate memory for b since dum() does that. Allocating memory for b before the call to dum() would cause a memory leak unless you freed it.

Comment: @MayankJain You do that in `dum()`

Comment: @MayankJain Why are you using raw pointers and `new()` at all? It's usually not necessary to do so in c++. You might be confused by java or c# concepts.

Answer (score 2):

From the RAII point of view you should not allocate inside `dum` and return a raw pointer.

Better options are:

- std::unique_ptr dum();
- std::shared_ptr dum();
- void dum(A&);

The first two return a managed pointer, while the third is expecting a reference which might be a stack or heap variable.

Another good option is returning by value (which should give an compiler optimized code, if `A is well written):

- A dum();

See also:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Rvalue_references_and_move_constructors

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ And it is should be just that (A function returning a value - not local)

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood your sample I thought it simply should demonstrate on stack allocation of `A` (which would be a good point to mention).

Comment: You should have kept my other edits, regarding source code representation.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ A matter of taste (It's cleaner this way, it is not referencing any code)

Comment: If you show code you should render it as such (since it improves readability. At least for me), but well, matter of taste maybe.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to assign a new A() to b, because by calling b = dum(), you already make b to point on the same memory location as a. Keep in mind that by using pointers, you don't assign content to b, you only assign a memory location address.

In fact, if you do b = new A(), and then do b = dum(), you will lost the reference on the memory location pointed by b in the first place, which will cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Both your examples are legal. There are better ways as others have suggested already but in principle your code is fine. I have tried to add some comments to explain what happens. Hope that clarifies it.

And "No - you don't need to reserve memory for b". The compiler handles it for you.

**Your first example**

```
A* dum()
{
    A* a;               // The compiler reserves memory for holding
                        // the pointer a on the stack. 

    a = new A();        // On run time you reserve memory on the heap
                        // for holding an instance of class A.

    doSomethingOnA(a);  // Some function call where you pass the pointer

    return a;           // Return the pointer. This will also release
                        // the stack memory used for holding the pointer a.
}
```

In another function:

```
void func()
{
    A* b;               // The compiler reserves memory for holding
                        // the pointer b on the stack. 

    b = dum();          // The value of the pointer b is changed
                        // so it points to the instance of class A
                        // which is in the heap. The pointer b is
                        // still on the stack.

    // ... more code

    delete b;           // Delete b to free the heap memory 
                        // (and call the class A destructor).

    return;             // This will release
                        // the stack memory used for holding the pointer b.
}
```

**Your second example**

The principles are the same.

And "No - you don't need the new inside the function dum(..).
In fact that would be an error.

```
bool dum(A* a)
{
  // As this function has no local variable, no stack
  // memory will be needed for holding variables.

  // A* a = new A() -- Is this needed?     NO - it would be a bug

  doSomethingOnA(a);

  return 1;
}


void func()
{
    A* b;               // The compiler reserves memory for holding
                        // the pointer b on the stack. 

    b = new A();        // On run time you reserve memory on the heap
                        // for holding an instance of class A.
                        // The value of the pointer b is changed
                        // so it points to the instance of class A
                        // which is in the heap. The pointer b is
                        // still on the stack.

    dum(b);             // Just a function call

    // ... more code

    delete b;           // Delete b to free the heap memory 
                        // (and call the class A destructor).

    return;             // This will release
                        // the stack memory used for holding the pointer b.
}
```

Note:
Compilers may optimize the use of stack so that local variables inside a function is kept completely in registers and therefor doesn't need any memory at all.